# T does not contain the definition for RowKey

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a generic class:

```
public class ClassName<T>
{
    public T AccessEntity(string id)
    {
        return (from e in ServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>(TableName)
                where e.RowKey == id // error here!
                select e).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

In this code I am getting error that:

> T does not contain the definition for RowKey

but the parameters which will replace the T at runtime have the definition of RowKey. Maybe because complier is not getting the definition for RowKey in T at compile time, that`s why I am getting this error. Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: As a comment - I upvoted one of the correct answers: the compiler does not CARE what T will be later. It cares about what it KNOWS at compile time, which means you CAN create ClassName<Dumbo> and Dumbo has no RowKey -> error. Adda constraint ;)

Comment: Pro illustrate TomTom's point: in c# you could write a type *at runtime*, and invoke the generic type for the new type -  as long as it meets the constraint, it'll work. This s very different to c++ templates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To do that you would need an interface constraint:

```
interface IHazRowKey {
     string RowKey { get; } 
}
```

And specify this restriction:

```
public class classname<T> where T : IHazRowKey {...}
```

And specify `: IHazRowKey` on each of the implementations:

```
public class Foo : IHazRowKey {....}
```

The existing `RowKey` member should match it (assuming it is a property, not a field), so you shouldn't need to add any other extra code. If it is actually a field (which it shouldn't be, IMO) then:

```
public class Foo : IHazRowKey {
    string HazRowKey.RowKey { get { return this.RowKey; } }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ICanHazRowKey? :)

Comment: thanks for answer , but the class which i am implementing as a generic class has drived from the other class, sorry for not mentioning this in question. Means it is something like : public class ClassName<T> : Base

Comment: @Tom that doesn't change anything; you are allowed multiple interface inheritance, and single class inheritance,

Comment: Is it possible to not add `: IHazRowKey` in a class implementation? E.g. I'd wanted to create a generic function to toggle hiding/expanding of a controls *(if there defined an according methods, of course)*, and here's, of course, no way to modify Microsoft's code.

Comment: @Hi-Angel are you asking "can an existing class be made to implement an interface"? if so: no. You would have to wrap it, decorator style. Unless of course it is simply *generated* code in the same assembly, in which case: "partial classes"

Answer (score 8):

There is a major difference between C++ templates and C# generics: it does not matter what classes you pass to instantiate the generic, if the compiler does not know about a method on `T` at the time of compiling your generic class or method, it would give you an error. This is because C# needs an ability to compile the generic code separately from its places of instantiation (remember, there are no headers in C#).

You can define an interface, and restrict `T` to it in order to use properties and methods inside a generic. Add `RowKey` to your interface, and add `where T : myinterface` to your generic declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to solve this:

```
public interface IHasRowKey
{
   string RowKey {get;}
}

public class classname<T> where T : IHasRowKey
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourClass // or extract an interface
{
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
}

class YourGeneric<T> where T : YourClass
{
    // now T is strongly-typed class containing the property requested
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My case can't use a interface to contain RowKey, cause I have two classes that have different Properties and methods. I can't just merge them and put these properties and methods into one wrapper interface or class, cause it loses the aim of using generic class. My solution is using reflection with Generic class. E.g.:

```
public class ClassName<T> {
    private T _genericType;
    public ClassName(T t) {
        _genericType = t;
    }

    public void UseGenericType() {
        // Code below allows you to get RowKey property from your generic 
        // class type param T, cause you can't directly call _genericType.RowKey
        PropertyInfo rowKeyProp = _genericType.GetType().GetProperty("RowKey");
        if(rowKeyProp != null) { // if T has RowKey property, my case different T has different properties and methods
            string rowKey = rowKeyProp.GetValue(_genericType).ToString();
            // Set RowKey property to new value
            rowKeyProp.setValue(_genericType, "new row key");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the reference to PropertyInfo class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.PropertyInfo_methods(v=vs.110).aspx